# Specifying the values after decimals should be changeable in C

Tags: c++, c, printf

I have written this code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float num = 10.23456f;
    printf("num = %.2f\n",num);
    return 0;
}
```

I got the output correctly as: 10.23.
But my problem is I do not want to specify the rigid number in the format like `%.2f`. I want to know if something like this statement occurs or not:

```
printf("num = %.{n}f\n",num,2); or printf("num = %.{n}f\n",num,5);
```

Means I can change in printing lively.
Kindly let me know.

Comment: Why the [tag:c++] tag?

Comment: @user3121023 The comments section is not for answering the question

Comment: @ Timo This is also compiling and running c++ code. If something is valid code for both languages i think it's fine to also add both tags to the question. If something compiles with a standard c++ compiler it is c++.